# Get Maximum value column from subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

i have a mysql query as

```
SELECT date,shortcode,SUM(count) as myCount 
FROM mytable 
WHERE smsc='123' 
  AND username NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+' 
  AND DATE(date) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY shortcode,date 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Which gives the result as following which is perfectly fine

| date | shortcode | myCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-18 | 123 | 7 |
| 2021-02-18 | 231 | 15 |
| 2021-02-19 | 783 | 117 |
| 2021-02-19 | 894 | 115 |
| 2021-02-20 | 009 | 70 |
| 2021-02-20 | 565 | 15 |

now what i want to do is get max value of maxcount from each day and corresponding shortcode so what i did is

```
Select date,Max(myCount) as maxim,shortcode 
from ( SELECT date,shortcode,SUM(count) as myCount 
       FROM mytable 
       WHERE smsc='123' 
         AND username NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+' 
         AND DATE(date) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
       GROUP BY shortcode,date 
       ORDER BY date ASC ) as a 
GROUP BY a.date;
```

which is not giving me the right result
my desired result is

```
date       | shortcode | maxim
2021-02-18 | 231       |15
2021-02-19 | 783       |117
2020-02-20 | 009       |70
```

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: has nothing to do with mysql version as i am getting MAX value right but shortcode value is wrong

Comment: You are grouping by date so shortcode is non determinate -

Comment: If you have MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10+, the answer to your question is much different (and shorter) than if you have an older version: the newer versions have [CTEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). With respect, you should not blow off @Akina's question about version.

Comment: See my edited question

Comment: the data in your above table doesn't seem to be grouped by date, as I can see dates being repeated. Why so?

Comment: cuz its first grouped through shortcode and then dates

Comment: @BensonOO is your problem resolved? If not please check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use common table expression and row_number() to achieve your desired result:

```
with cte as (
select date,shortcode,mycount,row_number()over(partition by date order by mycount desc) rn from (SELECT date,shortcode,SUM(count) as myCount 
FROM mytable 
WHERE smsc='123' 
  AND username NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+' 
  AND DATE(date) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY shortcode,date )t)
select date,shortcode,mycount from cte where rn=1
```

This query will generate a sequence for each date orderring by mycount in descendent order. So always the first row for each date will contain the max mycount.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a variable, the query is:

```
SET @x='';
SELECT
@x:=date,shortcode,myCount FROM (
  SELECT date,shortcode,SUM(count) as myCount 
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE smsc='123' 
    AND username NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+' 
    AND DATE(date) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
  GROUP BY shortcode,date 
  ORDER BY date ASC,myCount DESC
  ) a
WHERE @x<>date
;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/guUS5Nrf3N77Re5vh156ni/0)